# Probabilistic method proof clarification

Tags: probability

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

How did they get the probability in the first picture and the expectation in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Here's an overly slick way to see the first one, which cuts down on binomial coefficient calculations. (I didn't come up with it -- I've seen this in algorithms classes a few times. My sense is that an answer along the lines of what Rob gives is actually the 'right' approach, since carefully manipulating binomial coefficients is a general technique that answers these kinds of questions.)

Only the ordering of the nodes $v$ and its $n - d(v) - 1$ non-neighbors matter ($v$ is not a neighbor of itself). So, we are asking, if we order $n - d(v) - 1 + 1 = n - d(v) = m$ elements, with a special one called $v$, whats the probability that $v$ ends up first? Well, there $(m -1)!$ permutations where $v$ is first, out of $m!$ total. So the probability is $\frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{n - d(v)}$.

2.
The second one uses linearity of expectation and the orbit stabilizer theorem.

First we ask: how many copies of $H$ are in $K_n$?

Let's clarify that by a copy we mean an equivalence class of injective graph-homomorphisms $\phi : H \to K_n$, where $\phi \sim \phi'$ iff there is a $a \in Aut(H)$ so that $\phi = \phi' \circ a$. (I'm guessing that this is the intended meaning, but the answer works out so I think the guess is correct.)

The group $S_n$ acts transitively on the set of these by composition on the left, so to figure out how many there are we have to compute the size of a stabilizer. I claim that the order of the stabilizer is exactly $|Aut(H)| (n - v)!$ (proof below), which gives us $\frac{n!}{ (n -v)! |Aut(H)|}$ subgraphs isomorphic to $H$ by the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Each one appears with probability $p^{e(H)}$, so linearity of expectation gives the expected value, using $\# H = \sum_{\text{ copy , } \phi \text{ ,of H in K_n }} 1_{\phi 
 \text{ in G }}$ and $\mathbb{P} (\phi 
 \text{ in G }) = p^{e(H)}$.

Proof of claim: If $g \circ \phi = \phi \circ a$ for some $g \in S_n$ (thought of as a bijection from the vertices of $K_n$ to themselves) and $a \in Aut(H)$, then $im (\phi) = im ( g \circ \phi)$. In particular $g$ preserves the image of $\phi$, which we will call $I$, as well as its complement.

This means that $g$ breaks down into two functions: $g|_{I^c} : I^c \to I^c$, $g|_I : I \to I$. The actions are completely independent, so once we figure out how many choices there are for each piece, we multiply those numbers to get the number of choices for $g$.

$g|_{I^c}$ can be any permutation, so there are $(n - v)!$ choices for it.

The condition for $g|_I$ is that there is some $a \in Aut(H)$ with $g|_{I} \phi = \phi \circ a$. We want to calculate the size of the set $S' = \{ q \in Bijections(I) : \exists a \in Aut(H), q \phi = \phi a \}$.

When restricted to $I$, $\phi : H \to K_n[I]$ becomes a bijection (on vertices). In particular, $g|_{I} = \phi \circ a \circ \phi^{-1}$ (as maps of sets, $\phi^{-1}$ is not a graph homomorphism). To put this differently, $q \in S'$ is completely determined by $a$, and every $a \in Aut(H)$ gives on such $q \in S'$. So $|S'| = Aut(H)$.

Answer (score 2):

For the probability that $v$ precedes its $d(v)$ neighbors, condition on its position $k$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{d(v)+1} \binom{d(v)}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{d(v)} \frac{\binom{d(v)}{k}}{\binom{n-1}{k}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{d(v)} \frac{\binom{n-1-k}{d(v)-k}}{\binom{n-1}{d(v)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n\binom{n-1}{d(v)}}\sum_{j=0}^{d(v)} \binom{n-1-d(v)+j}{j}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n}{d(v)}}{n\binom{n-1}{d(v)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n-d(v)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling to do this calculation. I learned a few useful things from verifying this that I'll note here for other students: 1) ${p \choose t} / {s \choose t} = {s - t \choose p - t}/{s \choose p}$ if $s \geq p$ (in calculating with binomial coefficients one can look for a ratio of two binomial coefficients with the same bottom term), 2) To try to notice places where one can make substitutions to get things into the form of the hockeystick identity -- in particular, sums of binomial coefficients where the same term is being added/subtracted from top and bottom.